# LINHA EM HTML, NÃO CONSIGO DEIXAR UMA MESMA LINHA COM TRES CORES DIFERENTES

Tags: html, css

Rapaziada eu estou com uma duvida que não consigo entender como funciona.
EU SOU INICIANTE E ESTOU TREINANDO ALGUMAS COISAS.

EU GOSTARIA DE SABER COMO QUE EU FAÇO PARA DEIXAR UMA MESMA LINHA COM TRES CORES DIFERENTES, OU MAIS. EU NÃO SEI SE ISSO É POSSIVEL

MAS É UM BOM DESAFIO, JÁ PROCUREI EM ALGUNS SITES, MAS NÃO CONSEGUI ACHAR A RESPOSTA

-ABAIXO ESTÁ O CODICO QUE EU ESCREVI

EU QUERO UNIR AS TRES CORES EM UMA LINHA SÓ AZUL,VERMELHO E PRETO

---

[ESSE É O CODICO QUE EU ESCREVI, DEEM UMA OLHA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNyAu.jpg)

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Você colocou uma imagem do código e/ou mensagem de erro. Apesar de parecer uma boa ideia, não é! Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar o código e alterar algo dentro. Clique no link [edit] e **coloque o código/erro como texto**. Veja mais sobre isso nesses links - [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/3774), [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7816/3774)

Comment: O ideal é escrever o código e mantê-lo dentro da pergunta e não colocá-lo numa imagem. Sobre a linha, talvez você devesse usar um elemento `div` ao invés de um elemento `hr`. Veja um exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/u3fydg6h/

Answer (score -4):

Olá! Eu também sou um iniciante como você, eu tentei fazer usando o que sei de css e consegui o resultado que você queria, Sinta-se livre para alterar os tamanhos da hr como quiser.

`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <style>
    .hr {
      height: 4px;
      width: 20%;
      float: left;
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
  <hr class='hr' color='blue' align='left'><hr class='hr' color='red'><hr class='hr' color='black'>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo.

Comment: ENTÃO, EU ESTAVA TESTANDO O COD, E MUDEI O WIDTH PARA 35%( O CODICO SE DESFEZ)  AI MUDEI PARA 33% E DEU CERTO, PORÉM NÃO COBRIU 100% DA PAGINA DE UMA PONTA ATÉ A OUTRA. ((-EU TESTEI OUTROS METODOS E TAMBEM NÃO CONSEGUI))